# Unable to pass data to the previous viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im trying to implement delegate design pattern.

I have two view controllers as followsm

1. CallViewViewController
2. CEPeoplePickerNavigationController

This is my interface definition of `CallViewViewController`

```
@interface CallViewViewController ()<CEPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate>{

}

@property(nonatomic)CustomMessageClass * customMessageClassObject;

@end
```

In my implementation, i have of-course implemented the delegate method

```
-(void)cePeoplePickerNavigationController:(CEPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didFinishPickingPeople:(NSArray *)peopleArg values:(NSDictionary *)valuesArg
{
    NSLog(@"can populate the tableview");
}
```

This is the interface definition of my  second class,

```
@protocol CEPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate;

@interface CEPeoplePickerNavigationController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>{
    id<CEPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate> peoplePickerDelegate;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<CEPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate> peoplePickerDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CEPeoplePickerNavigationController *ppnc;

@end


@protocol CEPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)cePeoplePickerNavigationController:(CEPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didFinishPickingPeople:(NSArray*)people values:(NSDictionary *)values;

@end
```

when the user presses submit button,Im executing the following code,

```
 if ([self.ppnc.peoplePickerDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(cePeoplePickerNavigationController:didFinishPickingPeople:values:)])
        [self.ppnc.peoplePickerDelegate cePeoplePickerNavigationController:self.ppnc didFinishPickingPeople:sortedPeople values:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:self.selectedValues]];
```

But the data is not being passed back to the previous view controller. Why so?

**UPDATE**

i tried the following code to move form first to second view controller,

```
CEPeoplePickerNavigationController *nextVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PeoplePickerNavigationController"];
    nextVC.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:nextVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

but it throws the following error,

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setPeoplePickerDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101054800'

Comment: Is your first view controller accepting to the delegate?

Comment: no...the first view controllers delegate is not being called

Comment: Im using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

Comment: I guess  complete solution is given by @Saheb Roy

Comment: it is crashing the app

Comment: Don't pass `self` to the `peoplePickerDelegate` then. Pass a `CallViewViewController` object.

Comment: Make sure every outlet is connected properly.

Comment: of course it is connected properly

Comment: i tried passing it like  nextVC.peoplePickerDelegate = [[CEPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init]; but still it is crashing

Comment: Is your peoplepickerdelegate a variable declared in second view controller? Nextvc.peoplepickerdelegate = self . Here pickerdelegate is a variable right?

Comment: yes it is a variable

Comment: And you have given segue from first controller to second not second to first right ?

Comment: no Im using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

Comment: You have given segue in storyboard?

Comment: Your storyboard having segue and you might have given that an identifier right?

Comment: no i did not use segue.. I have updated my code

Comment: I am not familiar with objective-c I know swift but still I can explain you the scenario . You have to pass data from second to first . So create a protocol in second controller . Within that controller declare variable of type your protocol name.In your action button in second controller make sure you get the delegate from first controller  .To get delegate from  your first controller use prepare for segue method in first controller.

Comment: If you have given segue by storyboard make sure your identifier is correct. And it is connected from first to second controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass data using **Custom Delegate**

Write Below code on your CEPeoplePickerNavigationController's `.h` file

```
@class CEPeoplePickerNavigationController;

@protocol CEPeoplePickerNavigationController <NSObject>
- (void)previousViewController:(CEPeoplePickerNavigationController *)controller itemToSend:(NSString *)item;
@end

@interface CEPeoplePickerNavigationController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id < CEPeoplePickerNavigationController Delegate> delegate;

@end
```

on your moving to previous view controller event you need to put below code

```
[self.delegate previousViewController:self itemToSend:@"From Previous VC"];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:true];
```

On your CallViewViewController you just need to add below code on .m file

```
#import "CEPeoplePickerNavigationController.h"

@interface ViewController ()< CEPeoplePickerNavigationController Delegate>
```

Add method declare on previous view controller

```
- (void)previousViewController:(CEPeoplePickerNavigationController *)controller itemToSend:(NSString *)item
{
    NSLog(@"from CEPeoplePickerNavigationController %@",item);
}
```

make sure when you navigate to CEPeoplePickerNavigationController you need to assign delegate to self as below

```
CEPeoplePickerNavigationController *objVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CEPeoplePickerNavigationController"];
objVC.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:infoController animated:YES];
```

Comment: plz check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197175/unable-to-receive-callback-from-second-view-controller

Answer (score 1):

When you are moving from `CallViewViewController`  to `CEPeoplePickerNavigationController` , there must be some sort of navigation where you are pushing or applying segue to go the next VC.

Just add this line of code there -

**If you are using segue** --

```
CEPeoplePickerNavigationController *nextVC = [segue destinationViewController];
nextVC.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
```

**If you are using instantiate --**

```
CEPeoplePickerNavigationController *nextVC = [self.storyboard instantiateWithStoryboardid:@"YOUR STORYBOARD ID"];
nextVC.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
```

Once this is done, it will respond to the delegate from the next controller

## EDIT

Please clear your CEPeoplePickerNavigationController .h code to the following

```
 @protocol CEPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate <NSObject>

 - (void)cePeoplePickerNavigationController:(CEPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didFinishPickingPeople:(NSArray*)people values:(NSDictionary *)values;

@end


@interface CEPeoplePickerNavigationController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>{
ABAddressBookRef addressBook;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<CEPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate> peoplePickerDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CEPeoplePickerNavigationController *ppnc;

@end
```

Comment: Im using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

Comment: Editing the answer accordingly

Comment: the app shows an error at the point nextVC.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

Comment: What error is it posting? and plz check the syntax as i am posting this answer in a windows machine so i dont have access to Xcode to autocorrect the syntax as some characters might be a little off

Comment: I have updated the question with the error that I have got